# SQOOP issue with teradata connector powered by teradata and Avro

Tags: hdfs, teradata, avro, sqoop

I'm trying to use sqoop to import a table from Teradata to HDFS as a avrodatafile, but am having issues.

Everything is working ok when importing as textfile. However, when I add --as-avrodatafile to the end of my sqoop command, I get a NPE, i.e:

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop     java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfo(SqlManager.java:275)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnInfo(ConnManager.java:393)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnInfo(ClassWriter.java:1854)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.AvroSchemaGenerator.generate(AvroSchemaGenerator.java:71)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.AvroSchemaGenerator.generate(AvroSchemaGenerator.java:65)
    at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.imports.BaseImportJob.configureInputFormat(BaseImportJob.java:165)
    at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.imports.TableImportJob.configureInputFormat(TableImportJob.java:32)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:258)
    at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.TeradataManager.importTable(TeradataManager.java:273)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:507)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)"
```

Not sure what is going wrong

Comment: What is the scoop command you're using?

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://XX.XX.XXX.XX/Database=XXXX \
--username XXXXX --password XXXX \
--table XXXX --split-by XXXX \
--target-dir /sandbox/XXXX --as-avrodatafile;